# Smooth move and pinch of UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, gesture

I have an image view that I want to be able to move around, and pinch to stretch it. It's all working, but it's kinda jumpy when I start to do any pinch movements. The position will jump back and forth between the two fingers.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    startLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:mouth_handle];
    if([touches count] == 2) {
        NSArray *twoTouches = [touches allObjects];
        UITouch *first = [twoTouches objectAtIndex:0];
        UITouch *second = [twoTouches objectAtIndex:1];
        initialDistance = distanceBetweenPoints([first locationInView:mouth_handle],[second locationInView:mouth_handle]);
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:mouth_handle];

    CGRect frame = [mouth_handle frame];

    frame.origin.x += pt.x - startLocation.x;
    frame.origin.y += pt.y - startLocation.y;

    frame.origin.x = (frame.origin.x < 58) ? 58 : frame.origin.x;
    frame.origin.x = (frame.origin.x > (260 - mouth_handle.frame.size.width)) ? (260 - mouth_handle.frame.size.width) : frame.origin.x;
    frame.origin.y = (frame.origin.y < 300) ? 300 : frame.origin.y;
    frame.origin.y = (frame.origin.y > 377) ? 377 : frame.origin.y;

    if(frame.origin.x - prevDistanceX > 2 && frame.origin.x - prevDistanceX < -2)
        frame.origin.x = prevDistanceX;
    if(frame.origin.y - prevDistanceY > 2 && frame.origin.y - prevDistanceY < -2)
        frame.origin.y = prevDistanceY;

    prevDistanceX = frame.origin.x;
    prevDistanceY = frame.origin.y;

    CGFloat handleWidth = mouth_handle.frame.size.width;

    if([touches count] == 2) {
        NSArray *twoTouches = [touches allObjects];
        UITouch *first = [twoTouches objectAtIndex:0];
        UITouch *second = [twoTouches objectAtIndex:1];
        CGFloat currentDistance = distanceBetweenPoints([first locationInView:mouth_handle],[second locationInView:mouth_handle]);

        handleWidth = mouth_handle.frame.size.width + (currentDistance - initialDistance);
        handleWidth = (handleWidth < 60) ? 60 : handleWidth;
        handleWidth = (handleWidth > 150) ? 150 : handleWidth;
        if(initialDistance == 0) {
            initialDistance = currentDistance;
        }

        initialDistance = currentDistance;
    }

    mouth_handle.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, handleWidth, 15);
}
```

Any thoughts on how to make this smoother?

Comment: I'd stick the image into a UIWebView, and wouldn't bother with reinventing the pinch zoom functionality.

Comment: Don't take @Felix's word for it. That's definitely not what webviews are for. You should explore `UIScrollView`.

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment below, I'm not using a UIScrollView because I just want to modify the width of the image, and do so to only part of the image. If I use a UIScrollView, it would be scaling the entire image. Do you know of a way to use the UIScrollView and still achieve my goal here?

Comment: Jonathan: Look at this method: - (void)loadData:(NSData *)data MIMEType:(NSString *)MIMEType textEncodingName:(NSString *)encodingName baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL

I think UIWebView is perfect for this situation. Granted I don't know what else Jacob needs to accomplish, but if it's as simple as an image with pinch zoom functionality, then this can be accomplished with approximately 5 lines of code.

Comment: I don't want to just have zoom functionality for my image. I only want to be able to adjust its width. I also don't want to just transform the width, because I don't want to distort the ends of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By jumping between the fingers, do you mean that you can't distinguish between the first and the second finger?

What I would do is calculate the angle between the fingers. By angle I mean that if you would draw a circle with one touch as the center and the other on the edge of the circle, you could determine the angle between the point right above the first touch and the second touch.
If the angle difference between two events is bigger than .5Pi (1/4 circle) you can assume the touches got switched and you could correct for that.

I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a UIScrollview; it's built into that directly.

Comment: The image has a long narrow piece with two balls on the end. When I pinch, I don't want to scale the entire image, I just want to stretch the width of the image, and do so without distorting the balls on the end. So, I'm using a stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth. I want the smoothness of the UIScrollView, but do not want to scale the entire image.